# how to call Web Api 2 Refresh Token from the Jquery Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am using MVC 5 Web Api 2 with individual user account authentication. I have set the access token expiration of 10 seconds.

```
TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
// In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
AllowInsecureHttp = true,
RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider()
```

i want to call jquery ajax for refresh token " /Token, 
after expiration the access token[image]

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/token',
    method: 'POST',
    contentType:'application/json',
    data: {
        username: $('#txtUserName').val(),
        password: $('#txtPassword').val(),
        grant_type:'password'
    },
    success: function (response) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.access_token);
        window.location.href = 'Data.html';
    }
}):
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the returned `refresh_token` as well as the `access_token` after the successful login request:

```
success: function (response) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.access_token);
  sessionStorage.setItem('refreshToken', response.refresh_token);
  window.location.href = 'Data.html';
}
```

You then use this to call `/token` with a `grant_type` of `refresh_token`. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/token',
  method: 'POST',
  contentType:'application/json',
  data: {
    refresh_token: sessionStorage.getItem('refreshToken'),
    grant_type: 'refresh_token'
  },
  success: function (response) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.access_token);
    sessionStorage.setItem('refreshToken', response.refresh_token);
    window.location.href = 'Data.html';
  }
}):
```

It would potentially make more sense to store the refresh token in something with more longevity than the session, such as `localStorage` or a cookie.

Comment: Then how to get refresh_token after expiration (10 seconds) of the access_token

Comment: You can't. The refresh_token is sent once in the response from the `/token` request to log in - as I mentioned in the first part of the answer.

Comment: ok I understand that but how to call refresh token after 10 seconds when access token expired

Comment: You could use a `setTimeout()` to delay some code for a set amount of time. Although, I assume this is just for testing as this is really not how the access and refresh tokens are supposed to work.

Comment: If a user or client login to the application, after 10 seconds session have been expired and the application canceled, I want the user or client will be able to log in once and the session or token validate lifetime.How to do that...................

Comment: Change the `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)` to a very long date in the future - although again that's note how access/refresh tokens should work. To use them correctly the access token should be a relatively short time (eg. 1 hour), to allow the user to access your API/site. Meanwhile the refresh token should be a relatively long time, (eg. 60 days) to allow the user to return to your API/site within that time without needing to explicitly log in.

Comment: Hey there! I am saying that my code for getting refresh token is not working.

Comment: @LEARNINGSTUDENT I am looking for the same. Have you found any solution to this?